# Sci fi magazine with meat growing on a tree (in the 70's)

Tags: story-identification

I read an illustrated story in the late 70's or early 80's, where a man was apparently abandoned on some strange planet, starving. At some point of the story, there was a little tree with meat growing on it instead of fruits. 
I couldn't read at the time, but I have been really struck by this image and would really love to meet again this story, and finally read it.

Comment: It could have been an 'ambush...